# Segmentation Core Dump C++, In Constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

Hello I'm currently trying to make a program for an IsingModel and one of the obstacles is to make a class that holds an array.  The array that is held by this class is two dimensional and is full of of either -1 or 1's.  Since the length of the array is unknown until the class is created I used a class constructor to make this array.  The problem is somewhere in that constructor I must be trying to access memory I cannot since I get a segmentation core dump somewhere in that constructor:

```
#include <time.h> // So we can use time() function
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class isingModel {
    private:

    int length;
    int relaxationSteps;
    double fieldStrength;
    double couplingConstant;


public:
    //This is the block that throws the segmentation core dump
    isingModel() {
        int lattice[length][length];
        /*Now let's initialize the lattice */
        for (int i=1;i<length;i++){
            for (int j=1;j<length;j++){
                int randNum = rand() % 2; // Generate a random number between 0 and 1
                lattice[i][j]=2*(randNum-.5);


                cout << lattice[i][j];
        }
    }
    }
        void set_values (int,double,double,int);
        int area() {return length*fieldStrength*couplingConstant*relaxationSteps;}
};



void isingModel::set_values (int l, double H,double C,int duration) {
    length = l;
    fieldStrength = H;
    couplingConstant = C;
    relaxationSteps = duration;


}


    int main () {
        int L,duration;
            double hConstant,couple;
            cout << "Enter the length of the lattice: ";


cin >> L;
        cout << "Enter the stength of the field: ";
        cin >> hConstant;
        cout << "Enter the stength of coupling: ";
        cin >> couple;
        cout << "Enter the number of times to relax the system: ";
        cin >> duration;
        isingModel iModel;
        iModel.set_values (L,hConstant,couple,duration);
        cout << "area: " << iModel.area() << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `int lattice[length][length];`  -- This is not valid ANSI C++.  Arrays must have compile-time expressions to denote the number of elements.  Instead use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> lattice`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `length` before setting it with set_values().

Comment: Hmm would I be better off just initializing the lattice in set_values() to avoid this?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what you should do. :) You can't reference something which is not yet set.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply!  I only have one remaining problem and it is when I initialize the lattice in set_values() instead, then the lattice is no longer a class variable and I cannot use it in other class functions.  I guess my question is once I've initialized lattice inside set_values() how do I use it outside of that function like I can with the variables that are class variables such as length or relaxation steps?

Comment: As the value is entered dynamically, you must also allocate it dynamically. You can do it either with a two dimensional array or with a vector: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21909/Introduction-to-dynamic-two-dimensional-arrays-in